# How to organize connections by project in Toad for Oracle

Tags: toad

In Toad for Oracle the connections can be grouped by database (among other fields as user, etc) but in some of my projects we have different databases and I would like to have all of them grouped by project in the connection manager window.

I would like some kind of custom folder functionality where I can put my connections as my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the connections manager window, clic on Edit custom fields button and add a new field. This field will be added to each connection as a new column.

You can assign values to this column for each column using it as an aggregator. Then use this column as grouping field.

You can add more custom fields to add subgrouping capabilities.